# In a one developer scrum team, can there be multiple tasks in progress

Tags: agile, sprint

Our scrum master stated that there cannot be more than one tasks in progress when there is only one developer, is it required for an ideal sprint, if yes, then why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be only one active task *per person* because **Focus** is a core agile and [SCRUM value](https://www.scrumalliance.org/why-scrum/core-scrum-values-roles):

> **Focus**
>
> Because we focus on only a few things at a time, we work well together and produce excellent work. We deliver valuable items sooner.

Having only a single person on your team is strange, because you cannot be a team of one. Your team size should be 3-7 people if possible. But if you are a single person on your team, yes, you should have only one active task at a time.

Comment: there is one developer, one product manager and one scrum master

Comment: The scrum master and PO are not part of "the team". A team of one is hardly a team. You can probably call it a sandbox experiment, but having a scrum master watching over the process of a single person is wasteful and not very agile. If you get more developers later, that's cool, but SCRUM for one is... strange.

Comment: interesting fact that scrum is meant if the team is of more than one developer/QA?

Comment: Just google "scrum team size" and you will find lots of interesting articles. It's even in the word [team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team).

Comment: Within Scrum the "team" needs to be fully cross functional - with all the skills needed to complete a product increment - the chances are with a "team" of 1 there will be a skills shortage .... 

If there is one developer then how is that developer working on multiple tasks at the same time? if they are then their context switching - this is a form of waste.

Comment: SM and PO are part of the team.  Team implies collaboration and trust between all individuals on the team.  You're going to have a failed team pretty quickly if team members don't collaborate or trust the PO or SM.  6-7 people (including SM and PO) is the happy zone for a scrum team.  A "team" with 1 developer isn't a team.

Comment: @WBW Scrum defines three core roles, SM, PO and "team". So no, SM and PO are not part of the "team" as defined in SCRUM. But that's only a naming convention that SCRUM chose. That does not imply that you should not work well with both SM and PO or not trust them.

Comment: @nvoigt, those are roles, not a definition of who is or isn't part of the team.  SM and PO are differentiated because they have specific roles that differ from all other team members.  SM and PO are still part of the team.

Comment: @WBW: The term "team" is used in two contexts within SCRUM: The 'development team' (only the developers, no SM/PO) and the 'Scrum team' (including SM/PO).

Answer (score 4):

I had been in this situation (I'm the only one developer in the scrum team). Realistically, there are times that you will be at the end of road/running out of ideas and solutions. Instead of wasting time being unproductive, sometimes it is best to leave the work you are doing for the moment and do some easier or other tasks. Sometimes, the lightbulb on your head will just appear while doing other things. I think the scrum master should give some flexibility and don't need be too rigid. As long as the team are committed  and doesn't go out of the agreed deliverables of the current sprint, I think it should be ok. Although the developer should be have self discipline since frequent task switching can be unproductive as well.

Answer (score 0):

My scrum team (small game development group) checks out tasks in 3 hour chunks because our core productive hours rest in 3 hour chunks. If your scrum tasks have been prioritized, you should have some idea of the sequence of your upcoming tasks. Tasks estimated over 3 hours need to be broken down into sub-tasks if possible.